# Button Disappearing when clicking next in pager - table pagination

Tags: jquery, html

I am placing a button in-line with table pager but when I click next button in the pager , the button disappearing, i am not sure what is happening.

I have created a [fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/uoh5Lrgx/2/). This is the code I am using:

```
$table.trigger('repaginate');
var pager = document.querySelector('.pager');
pager.insertBefore(csvExport, pager.querySelector(':first-child'));
csvExport.style.float = 'left';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pager = $table.next().empty();
```

You are emptying the pager and adding only pagination buttons, but not adding the export button.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you move your csv button into the pager div and then empty the div, only recreating the pager buttons and not the csv button.

Remove the following line and it will work but you will have to restyle you export button to sit in the correct place:

```
pager.insertBefore(csvExport, pager.querySelector(':first-child'));
```

```js
$('table.paginated').each(function() {
  var $table = $(this);
  var itemsPerPage = 10;
  var currentPage = 0;
  var pages = Math.ceil($table.find("tr:not(:has(th))").length / itemsPerPage);
  $table.bind('repaginate', function() {
    if (pages > 1) {
      var pager;
      if ($table.next().hasClass("pager"))
        pager = $table.next().empty();
      else
        pager = $('<div class="pager" style="padding-top: 20px; direction:ltr; " align="center"></div>');

      $('<button class="pg-goto"></button>').text(' « First ').bind('click', function() {
        currentPage = 0;
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
      }).appendTo(pager);

      $('<button class="pg-goto"> « Prev </button>').bind('click', function() {
        if (currentPage > 0)
          currentPage--;
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
      }).appendTo(pager);

      var startPager = currentPage > 2 ? currentPage - 2 : 0;
      var endPager = startPager > 0 ? currentPage + 3 : 5;
      if (endPager > pages) {
        endPager = pages;
        startPager = pages - 5;
        if (startPager < 0)
          startPager = 0;
      }

      for (var page = startPager; page < endPager; page++) {
        $('<span id="pg' + page + '" class="' + (page == currentPage ? 'pg-selected' : 'pg-normal') + '"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
          newPage: page
        }, function(event) {
          currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
          $table.trigger('repaginate');
        }).appendTo(pager);
      }

      $('<button class="pg-goto"> Next » </button>').bind('click', function() {
        if (currentPage < pages - 1)
          currentPage++;
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
      }).appendTo(pager);
      $('<button class="pg-goto"> Last » </button>').bind('click', function() {
        currentPage = pages - 1;
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
      }).appendTo(pager);

      if (!$table.next().hasClass("pager"))
        pager.insertAfter($table);
      //pager.insertBefore($table);

    } // end $table.bind('repaginate', function () { ...

    $table.find(
      'tbody tr:not(:has(th))').hide().slice(currentPage * itemsPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * itemsPerPage).show();
  });

  $table.trigger('repaginate');
  var pager = document.querySelector('.pager');
  //  pager.insertBefore(csvExport, pager.querySelector(':first-child')); remove this line
  csvExport.style.float = 'left';
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 40em;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

thead {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

td {
  width: 10em;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

tbody {
  background: #ccc;
}

div.pager {
  text-align: right;
  width: 40em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

div.pg-goto {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #D0B389;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
}

div.pg-selected {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
}

div.pg-normal {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #D0B389;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="paginated">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">A</th>
      <th scope="col">B</th>
      <th scope="col">C</th>
      <th scope="col">D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>48</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>54</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>56</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>57</td>
      <td>58</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>60</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>64</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>68</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>69</td>
      <td>70</td>
      <td>71</td>
      <td>72</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>73</td>
      <td>74</td>
      <td>75</td>
      <td>76</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>77</td>
      <td>78</td>
      <td>79</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>81</td>
      <td>82</td>
      <td>83</td>
      <td>84</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>85</td>
      <td>86</td>
      <td>87</td>
      <td>88</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>89</td>
      <td>90</td>
      <td>91</td>
      <td>92</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>93</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>95</td>
      <td>96</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>97</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>103</td>
      <td>104</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>105</td>
      <td>106</td>
      <td>107</td>
      <td>108</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>109</td>
      <td>110</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>112</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>113</td>
      <td>114</td>
      <td>115</td>
      <td>116</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>117</td>
      <td>118</td>
      <td>119</td>
      <td>120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>121</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>124</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>125</td>
      <td>126</td>
      <td>127</td>
      <td>128</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>129</td>
      <td>130</td>
      <td>131</td>
      <td>132</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>134</td>
      <td>135</td>
      <td>136</td>
      <td>137</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>138</td>
      <td>139</td>
      <td>140</td>
      <td>141</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>142</td>
      <td>143</td>
      <td>144</td>
      <td>145</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>146</td>
      <td>147</td>
      <td>148</td>
      <td>149</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>151</td>
      <td>152</td>
      <td>153</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>154</td>
      <td>155</td>
      <td>156</td>
      <td>157</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>159</td>
      <td>160</td>
      <td>161</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>162</td>
      <td>163</td>
      <td>164</td>
      <td>165</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>166</td>
      <td>167</td>
      <td>168</td>
      <td>169</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>171</td>
      <td>172</td>
      <td>173</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>174</td>
      <td>175</td>
      <td>176</td>
      <td>177</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>178</td>
      <td>179</td>
      <td>180</td>
      <td>181</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>182</td>
      <td>183</td>
      <td>184</td>
      <td>185</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>186</td>
      <td>187</td>
      <td>188</td>
      <td>189</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>190</td>
      <td>191</td>
      <td>192</td>
      <td>193</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>194</td>
      <td>195</td>
      <td>196</td>
      <td>197</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>198</td>
      <td>199</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>201</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="csvExport">Export to CSV</button>
```